Is React running components even after the state variable holds the same value?
As per my understanding after understanding Effects, I got to know that React mounts and remounts a component in Strict Mode. Also it renders a component twice in Strict Mode. From further research I found out that React doesn't re-render a component if the setState function tries to set the same primitive value as present.
As per the above logic, React mounts and remounts the component during first render. So console.log prints "Hello" two times but the value of ref.current remains one, as during remounting the entire existence of the first component is erased and the component is mounted again. So ref.current holds 1.
Now after we click the button, React renders the component twice making the value of ref.current increase by two to 3, and console prints "Hello" two times.
Now after we again click the button, React doesn't changes the value of ref.current it remains 3 as re-rendering is not triggered because we are setting the same value. But still "Hello" appears twice.
Here is the code :
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

import {useRef, useState} from 'react';

export default function App(){
    const [flag, setFlag]=useState(false);
    const ref = useRef(0);
    ref.current+=1;
    console.log("Hello")
    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={()=>setFlag(true)}>Click</button>
            <p>Number of renders : {ref.current}</p>
        </>
    )
}

Is there any way that React uses to check whether the new value to be set is the same value as the present and in doing so it runs the component once again and hence "Hello" is shown again twice or is it something else. One more follow-up question : Is this component Pure? Because given the same props and state(true) in both cases the JSX remains same.

React uses a mechanism called Object.is to compare the new state with the current state.  The idea is, If the state remains the same, it won't re-render

I got it, but still the Hello gets printed twice. Explanation for that?

ref.current starts at 0 and increments by 1, making it 1.
Hello is printed to the console. Then you clicked the button which sets the flag to true, React sees there is a change in the state (from false to true), thus, triggers a re-render. the ref.current value is now 1 and hello is printed again

Not that.. all total "Hello" gets printed six times in Strict Mode and without Strict Mode its gets printed thrice.

@AkinniyiAkinbodeBolade Please run the code to check how the component behaves.
